# Long polling issue: No response received

Tags: android, long-polling

I have a issue and I need a help. I want to get updates from server via long polling. I'm using this library for server communication.   https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http. Here is a code what I'm using

```
private void connectService() {

    AsyncHttpClient httpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
    httpClient.setBasicAuth("key", "");

    BaseJsonHttpResponseHandler handler = new BaseJsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String rawJsonResponse, Object response) {
            Log.e(TAG, "success  body " + rawJsonResponse);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, String rawJsonData, Object errorResponse) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error " + throwable.toString());

        }

        @Override
        protected Object parseResponse(String rawJsonData, boolean isFailure) throws Throwable {
            Log.e(TAG, "response  body " + rawJsonData);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPreProcessResponse(ResponseHandlerInterface instance, HttpResponse response) {
            super.onPreProcessResponse(instance, response);
            Log.e(TAG, "pre progress " + instance.getRequestURI());
        }
    };

    httpClient.get(this, url, null, handler);
}
```

So I tested in browser and everything is work, but I didn't get any response on my device and also which library you is the best for using long polling?
Thanks

Comment: If I understand you correctly, nothing is logged even though the request has been processed on the server?

Comment: Android device <=4.3? Then long polling most probably is not compatible with your Android device. Look here for a long discussion what could be the reasons: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java/issues/250 - still unsolved.